# Providing analogue reference / VDA from inaccurate 12 V source

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, adc

My module is for automotive and hence sourced from a car battery. I have several analogue inputs (from sources in the car) sampled into a 3.3 V STM32F103 which will look something like so:
[image: Resistor divider to reduce 14 to 3.3, followed by clamp, unity gain op-amp then filter]

My problem is the varying voltage of the battery (15 V to 9 V possibly) which, without a reference means my samples won't mean a lot.

The STM32 however has a ref int shared with VDA (and VDD). So, could/should I use the same circuit to power the MCU (to provide reference)? If so is there a particular type of op-amp that would best suit?

I would have to power the VDD pins as well because (from the datasheet):

> VSSA, VDDA = 2.0 to 3.6 V: external analog power supplies for ADC,
> reset blocks, RCs and PLL (minimum voltage to be applied to VDDA is
> 2.4 V when the ADC is used). VDDA and VSSA must be connected to VDD and VSS, respectively

Or perhaps there is a better way of doing this? I suppose I could use another ADC just for the battery and then adjust the values with that..

I am not sure why STM32's have vref+ and vef- pins because they usually have to be same as VDD and GND anyways..

(I am usually in the digital domain - so please don't make any assumptions on my analogue know-how.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How accurately do you need to measure these input voltages, and how often?

Comment: For the reason of Vref+ and Vref-, it's mainly so you can add additionnal filterring on those to get more accuracy (depending wht else is connected to your 3.3V, it can be quite noisy. NB : most STM32 have the Vref- internally connected to ground, only a few have it as an external pin

Comment: Depending on the required accuracy, your 3.3V supply might already be good enough as a reference given that it most likely comes from a linear regulator.

Comment: @Elliot - Pressure/Temperature for example at 10s/sec - without a reference (using a lin. reg exact 3.3)  the result may be several degrees of depending on whether battery is 10 or 14 volts. I guess I should be using something with a dedicated ref..

Comment: @Sandro, I see, so 'connected' doesnt mean tied directly - some variation/filtering is expected/allowed.

Comment: @Jonathon, well yes I originally expected to use a 3.3V for other VDD pins, and the divider for the vref, till I found they needed to be the same. Using an exact 3.3 for the ref just means the ADC results wont be representive.

Comment: A linear regulator will **not** give you "exact 3.3". You say the "may be several degrees [off]" but several degrees **out of what**? What is the maximum reading? Several degrees of error out of 20 degrees max is easy...is that what you want?

Comment: @Elliot - sorry, when I said 'exact', I meant as oposed to the voltage divider. I havent been specific as this is a generic logger, though pressure and temperture would be the usual suspects, so I am assuming the source would be some kind of divider on the battery voltage. An automotive lead-acid battery may be between 10V and 14V so we are talking a fair magin of potential error.

Comment: I'm leaning towards just sampling the battery with an additional ADC and fixing in software, as with my limted know-how of op-amps I probably wouldnt choose the correct one even if powering the MCU through one was feasible. I was hoping for definitive answer on why one could or should not do that mind.